# JWPlayer context menu no longer shows Stretch options in version 6

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

In JW Player 5 we used to have the option:

"Stretching is uniform" in the context menu on right hand click of player.

However in JwPlayer 6 - the example below this is not present.

This is the player setup code:

```
jwplayer('player1').setup({
autostart: 'true', 
allowfullscreen: 'true', 
width: '100%', 
aspectratio: '16:9', 
image: 'http://sta.whatever.com/thumbnails/12345678.jpg?v=1', 
abouttext: 'Demo Video', 
base: 'http://sta.whatever.com/jwplayer6/', 
fallback: 'false', 
primary: 'flash', 
sources: [{ file: ' 
rtmp://streamsta.whatever.com/flash/mp4:12345678_hi.mp4' }, { file:   
'http://streamsta.whatever.com/flash/12345678_hi.mp4'}]
```

Can anyone explain why that might be?

I've tried removing the

```
 width: '100%', 
 aspectratio: '16:9',
```

Without any difference. I know you can start the player in a default stretch mode  with the 'stretching' option, its the user being able to change from that I'm interested in.

Comment: In JW6 that option was removed from the right click menu. We are on JW7 now, it isn't something we are going to add back any time soon, as this is the first request we have seen for adding back this feature.

Comment: thats good to know - thanks